# Multistage deployment with Ansible using Dynamic inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm using the AWS dynamic inventory script for ansible as described [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) to pull a subset of my EC2 instances based on their tags. I would like to set up a multistage environment where I can run my playbooks on DEV or PRD using this dynamic inventory script.

I have my project directory set up as:

```
ansible.cfg
inventories/
  -- dev/
    -- ec2.ini
    -- group_vars/
    -- host_vars
    -- inventory
  -- prd/
    -- ec2.ini
    -- group_vars/
    -- host_vars
    -- inventory
playbooks/
  -- playbook1.yml
  -- playbook2.yml
  -- playbook3.yml
roles/
site.yml
```

The `inventory` file in the `dev` and `prd` directories is [dynamic inventory script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.py).

I have each ec2.ini file set up to create a dynamic inventory based on AWS tags for dev or prd environments.

If I attempt to run `ansible-playbook -i dev site.yml` I get an error: `[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/ansibleadmin/dev_playbook/dev as an inventory source`

This method is supposed to work for static inventories--does it not work with dynamic inventories for some reason? What would be the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a warning:

> [WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/ansibleadmin/dev_playbook/dev as an inventory source

The directory in the warning message `/home/ansibleadmin/dev_playbook/dev` does not exist on your machine, according to the "project directory" tree which you posted above.

---

The correct command using a relative path (while in the playbook directory) is:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/dev site.yml
```

The correct command using an absolute path is:

```
ansible-playbook -i /home/ansibleadmin/dev_playbook/inventories/dev site.yml
```